# Merge pandas dataframes based on several conditions for a large dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I want to merge two data frames based on certain conditions. First, I want to match the Full name only then for the mismatch entries, I would like to consider First and Last names as a matching condition. I have two Dataframes as follows:

```
df1
first_name  last_name   full_name
   John       Shoeb     John Shoeb
   John      Shumon   John Md Shumon
   Abu        Babu      Abu A Babu
  William     Curl      William Curl   

df2
givenName    surName     displayName
John          Shoeb      John Shoeb
John         Shumon     John M Shumon
Abu           Babu        Abu Babu
Raju          Kaju        Raju Kaju
Bill          Curl        Bill Curl
```

I first merge them based on full name:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=df1['full_name'].str.lower(), right_on=df2['displayName'].str.lower(), how='left')
```

And add a `status` and `log` columns:

```
df3.loc[ (df3.full_name.str.lower()==df3.displayName.str.lower()), 'status'] = True
df3.loc[ (df3.full_name.str.lower()==df3.displayName.str.lower()), 'log'] = 'Full Name Matching'
```

So the resultant dataframe `df3` now looks like:

```
first_name   last_name     full_name    givenName   surName   displayName   status  log
John          Shoeb        John Shoeb      John      Shoeb    John Shoeb    True    Full Name Matching
  John        Shumon     John Md Shumon     NaN       NaN        NaN         NaN    NaN
  Abu          Babu        Abu A Babu       NaN       NaN        NaN         NaN    NaN
William        Curl       William Curl      NaN       NaN        NaN        False   NaN
```

**Expected Results**
Now I want to apply matching condition based on df1 (First Name and Last Name) and df2 (givenName and surName). The final dataframe should look like as follows:

```
  first_name     last_name     full_name    givenName   surName   displayName   status  log
    John          Shoeb        John Shoeb      John      Shoeb    John Shoeb    True    Full Name Matching
      John        Shumon     John Md Shumon    John     Shumon    John Shumon   True    FN LN Matching
      Abu          Babu        Abu A Babu       Abu       Babu      Abu Babu    True    FN LN Matching
    William        Curl       William Curl      NaN       NaN        NaN        False   NaN
```

**Question** For the second part i.e. First Name and Last Name matching, I was able to get it done using the dataframe's `itertuples()`. However, when the same operations are applied to a huge dataset it keeps running forever. I'm looking for efficient ways so it can be applied to a big chunk of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indicator=True` in your merges. Then compare if first merge and second merge were `"both"` (for example with `np.where`):

```
df3 = (
    pd.merge(
        df1,
        df2,
        left_on=df1["full_name"].str.lower(),
        right_on=df2["displayName"].str.lower(),
        how="left",
        indicator=True,
    )
    .drop(columns="key_0")
    .rename(columns={"_merge": "first_merge"})
)

df3 = pd.merge(
    df3,
    df2,
    left_on=df1["first_name"].str.lower() + " " + df1["last_name"].str.lower(),
    right_on=df2["givenName"].str.lower() + " " + df2["surName"].str.lower(),
    how="left",
    indicator=True,
)

df3["log"] = np.where(
    (df3["first_merge"] == "both"),
    "Full Name Matching",
    np.where(df3["_merge"] == "both", "FN LN Matching", None),
)
df3["status"] = df3["log"].notna()

df3 = df3[
    [
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "full_name",
        "givenName_y",
        "surName_y",
        "displayName_y",
        "status",
        "log",
    ]
].rename(
    columns={
        "givenName_y": "givenName",
        "surName_y": "surName",
        "displayName_y": "displayName",
    }
)
print(df3)
```

Prints:

```
  first_name last_name       full_name givenName surName    displayName  status                 log
0       John     Shoeb      John Shoeb      John   Shoeb     John Shoeb    True  Full Name Matching
1       John    Shumon  John Md Shumon      John  Shumon  John M Shumon    True      FN LN Matching
2        Abu      Babu      Abu A Babu       Abu    Babu       Abu Babu    True      FN LN Matching
3    William      Curl    William Curl       NaN     NaN            NaN   False                None
```

Comment: Will the second merge raise errors if there are duplicates in df3? I see this while running it over the large dataset.

Comment: Or should it be `df3` instead of `df1` in the second merge?

Comment: @AbuShoeb Depends on your logic, but duplicates usually cause problems in merges. You can use `df1` in second merge, but the key is to use the `indicator=True` parameter - and observe the `"both"` values.

Comment: If df1 is used in the second merge, it throws a key error. Any clues on that?